# Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs) with .pdf as filter

Tags: excel, vba

I want the user to select the path and the file name of a PDF file that they are exporting.

I created the below to display the SaveAs dialog:

```
Sub Test3()

    Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    With myFile
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .ButtonName = "&Save As"
        .initialFilename = "Export"
        .Title = "Save PDF as"
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "You have cancelled"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

End Sub
```

The value of `FileSelected` is later fed into the pdf export code.

I want to add a filter to the above FileSave dialog so that it only shows PDF as the file save type.

Currently the value of `FileSelected` ends up being "Driveletter:/Folder/Name.**xlsm**" so when I feed it into the pdf export it saves the pdf with xlsm extension.

I tried `.Filter.Clear` and then `.Filters.Add`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Never mind I figured it out:**

```
Sub Test3()

On Error Resume Next
Dim FileSelected As String

FileSelected = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(initialFilename:="Export", _
                                         FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
                                         Title:="Save PDF as")
If Not FileSelected <> "False" Then
MsgBox "You have cancelled"
Exit Sub
End If

If FileSelected <> "False" Then
MsgBox FileSelected 'where FileSelected is what I will be
                    'later feeding into the PDF Export Code
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `FileSelected <> "False"` does not work if excel isn't in english. You can do `VarType(FileSelected) = vbBoolean` then `FileSelected <> false`

Answer (score 1):

I added a loop within the option list to run through the file types and select the one I wanted.  It has its faults, but works...

```
For I = 1 To .Filters.Count
    fName = .Filters(I).Description
    If fName = "PDF" Then
        .FilterIndex = I
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :
.Filters.Add "*.PDF", 1
or
.FilterIndex = 25
Depends on the order number of PDF in the listindex you can know it from your Save as dialog ---> type:
Sub Test3()

```
Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
With myFile
.Title = "Choose File"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.ButtonName = "&Save As"
.initialFilename = "Export"
.Title = "Save PDF as"
.Filters.Add "*.PDF", 1
If .Show <> -1 Then
MsgBox "You have cancelled"
Exit Sub
End If
FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: gives me an error 438: Object does not support this method in Access 2010